# Window 7 is crashing (ACER Laptop)

Tags: windows-7, laptop, memory, crash

I have a question regarding Windows 7 and determining the possible causes for it crashing.

I have a ACER laptop which I purchased 1 year ago with Window 7 installed on it. It has worked fine, but then I wanted a memory upgrade, I open the laptop up and just to check, I remove the installed memory modules and put them back in just to see if it would work fine if I were to put new memory.

Now after that the computer worked fine, but 1 day later, it crashes which hasn't happened every since I first used it, then I shut it down left it for a while, it works fine for a week and a half and then unexpectedly crashes again. Now the crashes are occurring randomly.

Crash definition in my case: While running it randomly goes black screen, the lED power lights go off and then turn on with the computer restarting by itself. This has happen very random, I don't play games on my computer, the computer wasn't heating up or anything, last I remember I was running MySQl DB on my computer when it crashed

I ran the memory diagnostics for windows 7 and it completed both tests and reported no problems. Also I ran my antivirus and it didn't catch any problems either.

I didn't touch anything else while I opened the computer, so what can be causing the crash? How to find the point in the operating system that causes it to crash in Windows 7?

My suspicion are that it's the RAM but how can I be absolutely sure? Is there any other test I can run to confirm this?

My apologies if I have posted this question in the wrong place or if it has improper tags.

---

*Edit*: As advised, I ran memtest86, computer 1 test, 1 pass, ran for 1 hour: no errors found in memory.

Comment: The memory could still be the issue - it might not be seated right.  As it is intermittent, it could be fine for the duration of the tests.  You could try running http://www.memtest.org/ for a day or so.

Answer (score 0):

Use deox on the mem contacts.  I have seen problems with slight oxidation on contacts.  A Deox pen is very handy for such issues.